# read data from a file and insert into a database using bash or awk

Tags: mysql, bash, unix, awk

I'm very new in Bash and unix. I was assigned a task to extract data from a log called `errors.out` which uses the delimiter `|`. Here's an example of the data:

1423544401|video_load_time|5.0.0.37|i3|55.66.88.77|0.0|RAT|mike|5656519|6549943438483||album|||N/A||7149

so basically the data in order is delimited by `|` is the following:

```
   times
   eventKey
   appl
   devic
   devn
   sign
   ne
   State
   latude
   lde
   su
   buame
   tount
   assId
   eCode
   monitor
   duration
```

I need to count each of the eventkeys (video_load_time) and add their total duration.
Then I have to insert those two fields into a database which i have created.
My database has 2 fields `count` and `totalduration` under the table `counter`.
Does anyone has any ideas what I should use to accomplish this? I heard `awk` or `python` would be a good choice..

Comment: You can use MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` command to load data from a CSV file into a table. You could then use a SQL query to combine the data into a new table with the counts and durations.

Comment: How is ssh involved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F \| '{ duration[$2] += $NF } END { for(d in duration) { print d, duration[d] } }' errors.out
```

Here `$2` is the second field in each line and `$NF` the last, so this sums up the durations by key and prints the results when the end of the input is reached -- after everything is processed.

EDIT: To add a counter to that,

```
    awk -F \| '{ duration[$2] += $NF; ++counter[$2] } END { for(d in duration) { print d, counter[d], duration[d] } }' errors.out
```

Comment: wow thank you! this works really well
do you know what command can i use to count the number of video_load_time ?
 keeping in mind that sometimes that field is not always called video_load_time, sometimes is called crash, audio_load, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FS="|" -v KEY="video_load_time" '$2==KEY{TOTAL+=$NF}END{print KEY,TOTAL}'  my_file
```

for

```
-v KEY="video_load_time"
```

you can change the variable key string to any other value other than `video_load_time`